# jQuery UI draggable - Custom data disappears

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm having a weird problem with using jQuery UI Draggable and setting custom data.

My code:

```
$('.drag')
    .data('foo', 'bar')
    .draggable({
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            var foo = $(this).data('foo');
            alert(foo); // alerts 'undefined'
        }
    });
```

It seems it's losing all it's when dragging (console.log'ing $(this).data inside stop() shows an empty object). Is

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Silly silly me, I was doing a $(ui.draggable).remove() inside the drop-function of the droppable i was dragging the object into, so the object was removed before it could get any data. You would think that the draggable's 'stop'-event would be called before the droppable's 'drop' event though...

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jQuery UI 1.7.2 ?

I test it and every thing is working fine

check this [link on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ocixe/edit)

click [preview](http://jsbin.com/ocixe) to run the code.

Comment: Yes, I'm using 1.7.2, with jQuery 1.4. I can't really understand why it isn't working. Somehow the data object of $(this), inside 'stop' is an empty object, but if i console.log $('.drag').data() after my previous code, it shows the correct data.

Comment: instead of $(this) try use $('.drag')